# Bootstrapping data frame columns independently in R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` where each column represents a different individual and each row represents different food items eaten.

My goal is to resample each column via bootstrapping and then calculate a metric score and C.I.s for each individual (data column) using a defined function.

I have done this successfully on a single vector but cannot figure out how to apply the bootstrapping and metric function to individual columns in a data frame. Below is the code I have to apply it to a single vector:

```
data.1 <- c(10, 50, 200, 54, 6) ## example vector
## create function
metric.function <- function(x){
  p <- x/sum(x)
dap <- 1/sum(p^2)
return(dap)
}
vect <- c() ## empty vector for bootstrap data

for (i in 1:1000){
data.2 <- sample(data.1, replace = TRUE)  ##bootstrap sample ##
vect[i] <- metric.function (data.2)     ## apply metric.function ##
}

summary(vect) ## summary 
quantile(vect, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)) ## C.I.
```

This works fine for a single vector but I want to apply it independently to multiple columns in a data frame, for example in the `example.df` below I want to apply it to `x1:x10` independently resulting in 10 metric scores and 10 C.I.s

```
example.df<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

I have tried changing the `vector` item to a `data.frame` and messing around with `apply` and `dply` but cannot figure it out, can anyone suggest how to do it or point me in the direction of useful guide/website etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect chance to use `replicate` and `sapply`.

```
replicate(1000, sapply(example.df, function(x) 
  metric.function(sample(x, replace = TRUE))))
```

`sapply` will operate column-wise (given that a `data.frame` is in a sense a `list` of columns); once we've isolated a column within `sapply`, we need only resample it & apply our metric.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for!